# woocommerce sidebar not appearing after update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

Woocommerce shop page not showing sidebar after I update the plugin.
In widget section I have assigned a sidebar for shop page and customizer settings are also fine.
Please look into [this page](https://pukkacbdoils.com/cbd-shop) and help me to find out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Never update plugins without properly testing them first this is the golden rule.  Your sidebar is still there but the CSS in your style.css theme file needs modifying to move it into the correct position.

```
#sidebar {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advise, in future I will take care of that whenever update any plugin. I applied given css in custom css (customizer), still not showing sidebar.

Comment: It depends where your custom CSS is placed in the page.  If it loaded before the style.css code then it will be overwritten by the theme's stylesheet.  You can edit the elements on the page is Chrome Devtools and see the sidebar appear with that CSS I have documented.

Comment: I have checked my style.css #sidebar coding. It was same as you provided.

Comment: Change the CSS to this and you will see it appear again if you include the !important tags.  #sidebar {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 500px !important;
    left: 0% !important;
}

Comment: changed css with new one but still not showing sidebar.

Comment: It's appearing I can see it.  https://screenshots.firefox.com/jtVOW39oHTW04K5e/pukkacbdoils.com  Refresh your browser cache by pressing Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have deleted cookies and now it's showing. But it is not responsive. Can you please help me out to make it responsive.

Comment: Your sidebar is being hidden by this CSS for mobile devices @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.sidebar {
    display: none;
}

Comment: If you want it to stop from jumping around the page then set the position to be relative instead of absolute.  position: relative !important;

Comment: Tried new code with relative !important. It displaced sidebar in desktop view and mobile view is still not appearing.

Comment: Your theme hides the sidebar on mobile devices.

Comment: Relative !important code not working in desktop view also. Is there any solution to solve this problem or I need to talk with theme developer?

Comment: My biggest advice to you is to stop what you're doing and learn CSS.  You can override the CSS to enable it to display the sidebar on mobile devices.

Comment: I am still learning, so sorry to bother you again. Applied this setting for desktop - #sidebar {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 500 !important;
    left: 0% !important;
} and  this for media 768 px  @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .sidebar {position: relative !important;
    top: 500 !important;
    left: 0% !important;} } Now sidebar showing in desktop and mobile both. But in mobile it is overlapping text.

Comment: If you want it to appear at the bottom of the page then use this media query for the sidebar for mobile devices.   @media (max-width: 768px)
.sidebar {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0% !important;
}

Comment: Thanks for your help.